# TCL delete duplicate lines by 3 different pattern matching

Tags: tcl

I'm a beginner in programming TCL and want to delete lines from an input file matching

1. exactly the same line content
2. pattern: `"ghi\/\njkl\/\nrccu1" -> "Point \.*: 10 Sinks" \.*`
   (number behind word "Point" and content behind "`[color.*`" can be different - all other need to match exactly)
3. `"mno\/\npqr\/\nrccu1" -> "stu\/\nvwx\/\nrccu1" [label = "depth: 1"] [color=salmon] [fontcolor=salmon] [style=solid];`
   (number behind word "Point" and content behind "`[color.*`" can be different - all other need to match exactly)

Now I have following input file

```
"abc\/\ndef\/\nrccu1" [shape=octagon,color=red,style=filled];
"abc\/\ndef\/\nrccu1" [shape=octagon,color=red,style=filled];

"ghi\/\njkl\/\nrccu1" -> "Point 1: 10 Sinks" [color=salmon] [style=solid] [weight=8];
"123\/\n456\/\nrccu1" -> "Point 9: 10 Sinks" [color=grey] [style=solid] [weight=8];
"ghi\/\njkl\/\nrccu1" -> "Point 8: 10 Sinks" [color=grey] [style=solid] [weight=8];
"ghi\/\njkl\/\nrccu1" -> "Point 13: 20 Sinks" [color=grey] [style=solid] [weight=8];

"mno\/\npqr\/\nrccu1" -> "stu\/\nvwx\/\nrccu1" [label = "depth: 1"] [color=salmon] [fontcolor=salmon] [style=solid];
"mno\/\npqr\/\nrccu1" -> "stu\/\nvwx\/\nrccu1" [label = "depth: 4"] [color=salmon] [fontcolor=salmon] [style=solid];

"mno\/\npqr\/\nrccu1" -> "stu\/\nvwx\/\nrccu1" [label = "depth: 1"] [color=grey] [fontcolor=red] [style=solid];
```

Output file should contain:

```
"abc\/\ndef\/\nrccu1" [shape=octagon,color=red,style=filled];

"ghi\/\njkl\/\nrccu1" -> "Point 1: 10 Sinks" [color=salmon] [style=solid] [weight=8];
"123\/\n456\/\nrccu1" -> "Point 9: 10 Sinks" [color=grey] [style=solid] [weight=8];
"ghi\/\njkl\/\nrccu1" -> "Point 13: 20 Sinks" [color=grey] [style=solid] [weight=8];

"mno\/\npqr\/\nrccu1" -> "stu\/\nvwx\/\nrccu1" [label = "depth: 1"] [color=salmon] [fontcolor=salmon] [style=solid];
"mno\/\npqr\/\nrccu1" -> "stu\/\nvwx\/\nrccu1" [label = "depth: 4"] [color=salmon] [fontcolor=salmon] [style=solid];
```

Comment: What version of Tcl are you wanting to use for this?

Comment: Currently I'm working with tcl-version "8.4"

Comment: do all those backslashes appear literally in the input file?

Comment: Hi Glenn, yes they do :( I assume they need to be replaced first by an unique string like "XXx_xXX" to be able to make a compare.

Comment: Why is the last "mno" line missing? the `fontcolor` attribute is different so that line should appear in the output.

Comment: You don't need to do anything special with the backslashes: when Tcl reads a line of input, they are just seen as ordinary characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set in [open input.file r]
array set seen {}
while {[gets $in line] != -1} {
    # blank lines should be printed as-is
    if {[string length [string trim $line]] == 0} {
        puts $line
        continue
    }

    # create the "key" for this line
    regsub {\mPoint \d+} $line {} key
    regsub {\mcolor=\w+} $key {} key

    # print the line only if the key is unique
    if { ! [info exists seen($key)]} {
        puts $line
        set seen($key) true
    }
}
close $in
```

Comment: The last "mno" line is missing because the string before "color" is identical. Thank you for the code - unfortunately it's not working in my environment - "dict" is unknown :(

Comment: @Markus, updated to use an array instead of a dict. You need to be much more precise about your requirements: "the string before color" is not at all what you asked for in the question. After all: "all other need to match exactly"

Comment: Glenn: many thanks for your help! I've tried it and your solution is working perfect!